# What is the difference between an activity going in the background and an activity becoming invisible?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am new to android.I have learned that the onPause() method is called when some other activity comes in the foreground and onStop() method is called when an activity is no longer visible.Can someone please explain what's the difference between going in background and becoming invisible giving some practical example.

Answer (score 0):

Best example? A popup, your activity is still visible, so only onPause() is called. Becoming invisible is when another activity is launched, the app is sent to the background, the user switches to another app et.

Answer (score 0):

Think about two cases

***1. Calling Activity B as dialog***

In this case, some part of Activty A will be visible. So only `onPause()` method will get called for Activity A. And when you will be back from Activity B to A, `onResume()` of Activity A will get called.

***2.Calling Activity B as normal activity***

In this case, `Activity A` will be completely invisible, So `onPause()` and `onStop()` both will be called. And when you will be back from Activity B to A, `onRestart(), onStart() and onResume()` methods of Activity A will be called.

---

Have a look

Case 1: If you call normal activity. (Which is going to hide caller activity)

```
onPause()
onStop()
<------- Back to caller
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```

Case 2: If you call activity-as-dialog. (Which is going to partially hide caller activity)

```
onPause()
<------- Back to caller
onResume()
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever a dialog box appears on any activity then activity's onPause() called and this activity holds the first position in stack(Top), on the other hand whenever we switches activity from one to another the previous activity's on Stop() method called and its automatically garbage collected in sometimes.